# Pivot the columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server table with the structure as shown in the 1st picture. This has to be displayed as shown in the 2nd picture. How to achieve this in SQL Server 2000?

[image]

Comment: I removed the SQL-Server-2005 tag, since your question seems to be about 2000

Comment: Sql Server 2000 past it's end of life date a couple years ago. In that time, it hasn't received any updates... not even basic security updates. It's therefore highly-irresponsible to continue using it. Your first order of business is to sell your management on the need for an upgrade.

Comment: To address the question more directly, though: there are some pivot options in Sql Server, but all of them need to know at least some information about the number, type, and/or names of the columns to be included in the final result set. With just A1 and A2, you may be able to do something. If you need to dynamically support A3..An, you're only option is dynamic sql.

Comment: but our Org still use 2000!!.We are a small org

Comment: Small is irrelevant: it's unsafe and irresponsible not to upgrade. If you're really that small, the Express Edition is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that same pattern for all records (_A1, _A2) something like the following should work for you: add in the extra columns and/or take out the unnecessary ones as you wish.

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1) AS Measure,
  LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1) + '_A1' AS Measure_A1, --Not sure you need this
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A1' THEN YTD ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_A1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A1' THEN Q1 ELSE 0 END) AS Q1_A1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A1' THEN Q2 ELSE 0 END) AS Q2_A1,
  LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1) + '_A2' AS Measure_A2, --Not sure you need this
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A2' THEN YTD ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_A2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A2' THEN Q1 ELSE 0 END) AS Q1_A2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(measure,2) = 'A2' THEN Q2 ELSE 0 END) AS Q2_A2
FROM Structure
GROUP BY LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edb97/7)

Comment: thanks...it works when i added GROUP BY LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1), LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1) + '_A2' ,  LEFT(measure, CHARINDEX('_', measure)-1) + '_A1'
order by measure